# Getting behaviour like Python 3 html unescape in Python 2

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, escaping, html-entities

So I've encountered an issue where it seems like Python 2 (2.7.13) simply doesn't have the required HTML entities defined for escaping all of them.

For example when running this script:

```py
# test_unescape.py

from six.moves.html_parser import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser()
# Print in a tuple for clarity
print((h.unescape('&pound;&lt;&Tab;&NewLine;&Colon;'),))
```

You get different results depending on Python version.

Python 2:

```
$ python test_unescape.py
(u'\xa3<&Tab;&NewLine;&Colon;',)
```

Tab, Newline and Colon are left escaped

Python 3:

```
$ python3 test_unescape.py
('£<\t\n∷',)
```

All unescaped

It's also unclear to me why I'm getting two colons in the Python 3 example.

Any workarounds to get the Python 3 version or something equivelant in Python 2 without manually defining all the missing entities (And therefore having to maintain it with future entities...) would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problems in [this library](https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/)

More specifically in the complete list of entities located in `html5lib.constants.entities`

```py
import html5lib

def unescape_custom(s):
    ents = html5lib.constants.entities
    for e in ents:
        if e[-1] != ';':
            e += ';'
        s = s.replace('&{}'.format(e), ents[e])
    return s
```

Results:

```py
# Python 2
>>> print((unescape_custom("&pound;&lt;&Tab;&NewLine;&Colon;"),))
(u'\xa3<\t\n\u2237',)
# Python 3
>>> print((unescape_custom("&pound;&lt;&Tab;&NewLine;&Colon;"),))
('£<\t\n∷',)
```